# Como eu deleto um arquivo, que tem aspas no nome, pelo CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd

Eu estou deletando uma pasta do meu HD e pude apagar tudo, exceto esse arquivo.

Porque ele tem aspas, eu não posso usar nomes curtos, e não posso apagá-lo do jeito que está.

Eu tentei `fsutil file setshortname`, mas eu não consigo manter as aspas em `mai_68`

Eu tentei aspas duplas, `\`, e outros caracteres especiais, como `%`, mas as aspas não são reconhecidas pelo shell, como vocês podem ver:

[image]

Comment: Mesmo com o espace para a `"` que é usar `""`, não consegui remover o ficheiro. Já tentei diversas formas mas tudo sem sucesso! Linux Live CD, apagar ficheiro, reiniciar ;)

Comment: @Zuul Publique sua sugestão como uma resposta. Eu tentei de tudo no Windows, inclusive usar editores de disco (WinHex, HxD, DiskExplorer), pra tentar renomear o arquivo à força, mas no Windows 7 dá acesso negado... os drivers de acesso ao disco o protegem contra escritas, sendo que a única forma seria desmontar a unidade para depois editar (ai o driver deixa). Acontece que o caminho é muito longo e chato, ou impossível no caso do drive de sistema... parece mais fácil fazer download de uma distro de Linux Live pequena, colocar num CD ou USB e então fazer da forma que você disse.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Meti agora a resposta sugerindo uma LiveCD. Estive a tentar outros métodos que não os que indicaste e/ou já havia tentado, mas sem sucesso! LiveCD, 5min e tá arrumada a questão :)

Answer (score 7):

### Caracteres reservados

Em Windows, existem alguns [caracteres que são reservados](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> pois servem um propósito ao serem utilizados pelo sistema operativo:

- `<` (menor que)
- `>` (maior que)
- `:` (dois-pontos)
- `"` (aspas)
- `/` (barra)
- `\` (barra invertida)
- `|` (barra vertical)
- `?` (ponto de interrogação)
- `*` (asterisco)

Estes caracteres não são permitidos em nomes de ficheiros ou directorias dado serem reservados, mas isso não quer dizer que não venham a estar presentes nos mesmos, dado que muitos sistemas operativos que não o Windows, permitem o seu uso.

Confrontado com ficheiros ou directorias que usem estes caracteres, torna-se difícil resolver o problema a partir de um sistema que não permite o seu uso, pelo que, uma solução passa utilizar outro sistema operativo para os renomear ou remover.

### Solução

Felizmente, usar outro sistema operativo nos dias de hoje não requer mais que meia dúzia de minutos, como é o caso das LiveCD de Linux:

1. Descarregar um [ISO de Linux](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php);
2. Descarregar e executar [este](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button) ou outro software para criar uma PEN de arranque;
3. Da lista de opções, escolher a distribuição correta, se do link que deixei em cima, será a opção "Linux Mint";
4. Escolher o ficheiro ISO da distribuição que descarregaste;
5. Criar a PEN de arranque.

Depois de criada, basta usar a mesma para arrancar com o computador, escolher a opção de "Experimentar".

Answer (score 2):

Na linha de comando, e com o diretório corrente no local onde estão os arquivos, digite:

```
dir /x
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os nomes envoltos pela borda laranja são os nome em formato 8.3.

Com o nome curto do arquivo, você poderá exclui-lo.

Fonte: https://superuser.com/a/381516/90552

Comment: Nope, sem sucesso comigo! O problema é que `"` é um carácter ilegal para nomes de ficheiros ou diretorias... o próprio windows nem deixa criar ficheiros que contenham `"` no nome.

Comment: @Zuul Eu não consegui criar um arquivo com aspas duplas pra testar... você saberia como fazer isso pra que eu teste aqui?

Comment: Eu criei usando Linux, em Windows não consegui. Tenho os dois sistemas em paralelo, mas podes usar um LiveCD para rapidamente criares o ficheiro e voltares para o windows.

Answer (score 1):

O Windows não reconhece arquivos que tenham [**caracteres especiais**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions), portanto ele entende que se trata de um arquivo inválido. Uma maneira de remover esses arquivos é executando o [`chkdsk`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc730714%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) com  o parâmetro `/f`.

```
chkdsk o: /f
```

Onde `O:` é a partição onde se encontra os arquivos inválidos a serem corrigidos. Depois de terminado a operação, uma pasta chamada `O:\found.000` será criada contendo o arquivo que agora pode ser deletado.

O valor *000* pode mudar dependendo da quantidade de arquivos inválidos encontrados.

Para deletar, entre na pasta  `found.000` (use `cd LETRA` para acessar a partição):

```
>cd found.000
```

Depois delete todos os arquios com a extensão `.chk`:

```
> del *.chk
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102043/how-to-delete-a-ntfs-filesystem-file-whose-name-contains#comment206207_102081